# Open function does not work from terminal when using argv in code - python

Tags: python, terminal, argv, sys

I have this code:

```
from sys import argv 
script, filename = argv 
txt = open(filename) 

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename 
print txt.read() 

print "Type the filename again:" 
file_again = raw_input("> ") 

txt_again = open(file_again) 
print txt_again.read()
```

When I run it in terminal the text file won't open. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What is the error you get?

Comment: Opening a file does not mean a notepad or similar editor will open with the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the follow two lines, what you're saying is asking the interpreter to read 2 arguments:

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
```

So when you save your code as `test.py` and you try to run the code below you get a `ValueError`, because it only `$ python test.py` only have one argument.

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    script, filename = argv 
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Let's say you have a textfile call `in.txt` and it only contains the text `Hello World`, and you try to call the script with the `in.txt` as second argument, it runs:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ echo "Hello World" > in.txt
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py in.txt
Here's your file 'in.txt':
Hello World

Type the filename again:
>
```

**Note:** The first line is just a fancy way to create `in.txt` file with text *Hello World*

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm for a nice tutorial on using argv =)

Answer (score 0):

It maybe happening because of exceptions. The file may not be existing or you argument maybe an invalid string file name or the file maybe password protected.

you could try and catch the exception by using a try block and then carry on.